# Trying to find correct jQuery selector for an element

Tags: jquery, ajax

Here is an example of my markup:

```
<li class="websites" id="3">
    <span class="id">3</span>
    <span><a href="http://www.google.com"><span class="url">www.google.com</span></a></span>
    <span class="action"><span class="edit">edit</span> | <span class="delete">delete</span></span>
</li>
```

and here is my jQuery where I am attempting to pass the id of this website (`3`) to another script via ajax.

```
$('.delete').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).find('span.id').html();

        $.ajax(
            {
                type:    "POST",
                url:     "edit.php",
                data:    ({"id":id}),
                cache:   false,
                success: function(message)
                {
                    $('#'+message).fadeOut('slow');                 
                } // end AJAX return
            }); // end AJAX call
    });
```

When I check my POST headers I can see that the value of `id` is null so obviously my attempt at trying to set it is wrong.

As you can see I have the id in the actual `li` element plus another span with class `id` aswell that have the same value.

It doesn't matter which one is used for this bit of functionality.

Thanks.

Comment: The correct answer has been posted. However, you really should learn to debug this. The easiest way is to use `console.log` on the stuff that you're trying to select, and see if it matches. If not, cut and try a simpler select. `console.log($(this).find('span.li'))` outputs an empty list? See what is `console.log($(this))`. Notice that it has no descendants to search. Figure out you need to go up a level somehow. Then hit jQuery selector documentation to see how to do that (`parent` or `closest`).

Comment: @Amadan I wish so badly that I could properly +1 that.  The lack of debugging in questions (in general, not aimed at the question asker) is depressing.

Comment: Thanks @Amadan, I have never had to use `parent` or `closest` before but shouldn't be a problem in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var id = $(this).closest('li.websites').attr('id');
```

Closest finds `$(this)` ancestor that matches the selector, in your case, it's `li` with class `websites`

http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 2):

You can try this selector

```
var id = $(this).closest('li').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 2):

Tested, it works.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('.delete').click(function(){

         var id = $(this).parents('li.websites').children('span.id').html();


        });


    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var id = $(this).parent().parent().get(0).id;
```

Comment: hmm, wouldn't this select `<span class="action" />` ?